# Unqualified Element with Qualified Type Reference

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am essentially trying to produce the following chunk of XML from JAXB Annotations.

```
<pCredentials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="ns3:LoginCredentials">
        <loginId>user</loginId>
        <loginPassword>password</loginPassword>
        <userType>super</userType>
     </pCredentials>
```

I tried the following annotations and multiple variations of the same type:

```
@XmlElement(name = "pCredentials", namespace = "##default", type = com.foo.LoginCredentials.class)
private LoginCredentials pCredentials;
```

But it produces the following:

```
   <pCredentials>
        <loginId>user</loginId>
        <loginPassword>password</loginPassword>
        <userType>super</userType>
     </pCredentials>
```

Any suggestions as to what type of annotations I can provide that will produce the type reference?

Thanks for the help...Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JAXB implementation will only add an `xsi:type` attribute when the Java type of the value does not match the expected type of the element.  This is why what you tried will not work (since you are saying the elements type is the same type as the value.

You could do the following:

```
@XmlElement(type = Object.class)
private LoginCredentials pCredentials;
```

**Note**

- The `xsi:type` attribute will be required in the XML being unmarshalled.
- You will need to include `LoginCredentials` in the list of classes given to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Comment: Thanks a ton...this was a totally simple fix and it worked. Great blog posting too...it helped clarify my issue.